# How to get the prototype property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I define an object using function

```
AAA = function ( x) {
    this.x = x || 0;
};
```

Then I created on object using

```
 var a = new AAA();
```

If I am using a.prototype, I get "undefined". I can only use AAA.prototype to access the prototype property, I would like to know why?

Comment: Er, because `a` and `AAA` are different objects and only one of them has a `prototype` property?

Comment: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/

Comment: You are confusing the internal `a.[[Prototype]]` and the non-internal `AAA.prototype`